# как заменить данные input -ov из массива js, jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

массив может менятся к прмиеру щас он такой типа 
var data = ['500', '30', '78'];

нужно поменять value первый 500, второй 30 третий 78  и т .д.

```html
@foreach($param_default as $parameter)
                    <div class="row input_block">
                        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{$parameter->id}}" class="field id">
                    </div>
                                     
@endforeach
```

Comment: что на что должно замениться?

Comment: data = ['500', '30', '78']; 500 это первый id, 30 второй 78 третий м ит.д. т.е сколько в масиве столько строк и html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = ['500', '30', '78'];
var $inputs = $('input[name="id"]');
for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(data.length, $inputs.length); i++) {
  $inputs.eq(i).val(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @junior Пожалуйста. Успеxов!